# Is Content Database Encryption Supported?

Tags: content-database

There are some folks in IT that are interested in Encrypting all of the SharePoint Databases, specifically the Content Databases.  Is this a wise option and is it supported?  We will be using SP2016 with SQL 2016.

Bismarck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transparent Data Encryption is fully supported. Another option is BitLocker on data volumes.

Comment: Is Encrypting the Content Databases common in most SharePoint Environments? How often do you see this ?

Comment: I've rarely seen TDE employed. But I've run multiple farms where BitLocker has been enabled on data volumes (SQL and SharePoint).